# Differentiate between two buttons on a form and perform the required action on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a customerDetails.php page which shows customer data using a url which looks like

```
 localhost/customermanager/customerdetail.php?customerID=2 url.
```

As you can imagine, i get the customerID using the `$_GET['customerID']` php code. Now, i have two buttons that can reject or approve a customer. These buttons are on the same page. So what i'm trying to do is to identify which button was clicked and perform an update query accordingly. The update queries are on the same page, so the form's action is set to # or self. 
The problems is, when i click the button the form submits but the url changes to something else and it removes the `customerID=2` part. Since the page loads a customer's detail information, it will throw an error since it can't find the `customerID=2` part on the URL.
So is there a way to have two buttons on a single form and detect which one was clicked, and then perform an insert statement on the same form. 
If there is a better way of doing, im willing to try it out.

Thanks

Comment: Use input hidden type in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the customerID value as an additional (hidden) input field inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="2" />
```

That way the value can easily be passed between the pages without getting lost. You could also use a session variable for this. Both approaches have pros and cons. The above approach is the easiest.

Sometimes it make things easier when picking runtime arguments in a centralized but flexible manner at the initialization of the script:

```
if ( FALSE=== ($customerID = (   isset($_POST['customerID']) 
                              && is_numeric($_POST['customerID']) ) 
                                 ? (int)$_POST['customerID'] 
                                 : (   isset($_GET['customerID'])
                                    && is_numeric($_GET['customerID']) )
                                       ? (int)$_GET['customerID']  
                                       : NULL) )
  throw Exception('No numeric customerID value specified at runtime');
```

Also I often implement a customer exception class which accepts some additional details and logs itself to a custom logfile when it gets raised. This pushes such error handling code into separate files and keeps the main code clean and compact.

Comment: Ok, let's assume that i made the hidden input like this

<input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="$_GET['customer_id']" />

So how would i get customerID value when the page loads. I mean when the button is clicked the page loads and i think i have to to try and 
 get and the customerID from the url first using
    $_GET['customer_id']. 
If that doesn't work( Meaning it's after i clicked the button), it has to try and get the value from the hidden input right?

Comment: Correct, you get the value from the request arguments, so from the url by looking for the values inside the $_GET variable. But that is the same in _both_ situations. You _always_ get that id from either $_GET (or $_POST if you chose a POST method for your form). So there is no need to implement different strategies. You look into $_GET, either the value is there or something has gone wrong. Simple.

Comment: I guess my problem was with the post method of my form. i choose that and wrote the code which will choose which button was clicked and execute the query.

if (isset($_POST['approveButton']))
{
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET  Approved = 1  WHERE id = 4" );

}

Comment: Sure, in that case you have to check _both_ superglobals. I added a few lines to the answer implementing such a check in a generalized way. I often implement such "argument fetching lines" for required arguments in a block at the begin of a script. That way I can detect, convert and prepare all such arguments in a central place and don't have to bother with that further down. This keeps the real code cleaner and compact.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is intentional that customerID is removed when the second button is pressed.
In such cases, simplest solution is to do a

```
if ( isset( $_GET['customer_id' ) ) {
/* process customer id part */
}
else
{
     /* Second button part */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check your data, using `isset()`

For example:

```
if (isset($_GET['customerID'])) {
    // do something.
}
```

Of course, you want the code neat. So you can make a wrapper function, like so:

```
function get($item) {
    return (isset($_GET[$item]))? $_GET[$item] : false;
}
```

I think your problem is that you reload the page when you click on a button. So, instead making the input type to `submit`, you instead use `button`. Also, use a hidden input to store your value when an user presses on `approve` or `unapprove`.

From there, you can bind the buttons to event handlers (we will use click()):

**HTML Buttons and hidden input:**

```
<input type="button" id="approve" value="Approve" />
<input type="button" id="unapprove" value="Unapprove" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected" value="false" />
```

**JavaScript Handlers:**

```
document.getElementById('approve').onclick   = function() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value= true;
};

document.getElementById('unapprove').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('selected').value= false;
};
```

Now you don't need to reload the page (which saves server-bandwidth and loadtime).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but where exactly would i put the query for the update statements.
Meaning if its the approve button that was clicked, i have to have the query that looks like 
    UPDATE customers SET  Approved = 1  WHERE id = 35
and if the reject button is clicked
something like    UPDATE customers SET  Approved = 0  WHERE id = 35

Comment: Because the page doesn't reload, you have `customerID` in the `URL`. You can get this value with your current code (`$_GET['customerID']`) Also, you know which button is selected by checking the hidden input `selected`. Add `name="selected"` to this input and you can get the data from it through PHP. If the `form method="POST"`, use `$_POST`; if `method="GET"`, use `$_GET`. Come to think of it, why don't you just use radio boxes? It doesn't reloads the page and you achieve the same results?